# How can I read and export a shapefile (.zip) in android studio using GeoTools?

Tags: android-studio, google-maps, shapefile, geotools

Im creating an app where you can draw your land(polygon) and save it in Firebase.Now I have a zipped Shapefile which contains geographical data which I want to read (and export) in Google Maps using Android studio. I installed GeoTools but I cant find a way to do it. Can someone provide me with some sample code or another way to do it?

Comment: Geotools does not support android

Comment: How can I read and export a shalefile in android?